# Javascript functions with AJAX request inside are not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert("test");
    ajaxrequest();
});
function ajaxrequest()
{
    alert("test");
    $.ajax({
        url:"/CRUD_LOGIN/php/getUserRank.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(result){
            alert(result);
            if(result.rank == "A")
            {
                $("#bar").append("<li><a href='/CRUD_LOGIN/page/display.php'>Admin panel</a></li>");
            }
        }
   });
}
```

but it isnt executed, and even the alerts are ignored... by the way, the getUserRank.php does this:

```
echo json_encode(array("rank" => "A"));
```

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? Did you include the jQuery library? If so did you put it before this code?

Comment: Well, if you strip out the AJAX [the alerts certainly work](https://jsfiddle.net/gjop8g8v/), so something else is going on.

Comment: this js file is included in my profile.php file, which contains header.html, which calls bootstrap and jquery libraries... so I think I did, hopefully that's not the problem

Comment: you should add an error function instead of having only a success. A lot of people do this, but even in production code, this can be helpful..

Comment: thanks for the tip Kaddath, will do it right now while I wait for an answer: do you know why, even if this script is called in the file profile.php, where jquery is also included, it still doesnt work?

Comment: As it is, i don't see why.. that's why for the error function, it can help find the reason.

Comment: Since you get `$ is not defined` check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: solved, apparently the problem was that i was calling this script before including jquery in the profile.php file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a line like this in console:
`$ is not defined`
you haven't included jQuery or not above `$(document).ready(function()` script

Comment: I actually have that line in my console, but as I wrote in the other comment: 
 
"this js file is included in my profile.php file, which contains header.html, which calls bootstrap and jquery libraries... so I think I did, hopefully that's not the problem", so I think it's not enough?

Comment: include jquery lib in the <head> to avoid this problem, not in your profile.php